# Camel AWS SQS and concurrentConsumers

Tags: concurrency, apache-camel, amazon-sqs

Camel version: camel-aws2-sqs-starter: 3.12.0

I am trying to use and understand concurentConsumers with a SQS queue:

```
from("aws2-sqs://queuexxx?concurrentConsumers=5&amazonSQSClient=#sqsClient&waitTimeSeconds=20")
                .process(exchange -> {
                    System.out.println("Message received...");
                    })
                .process(exchange -> {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }});
```

With the above queue, if I send 3 messages at the same time, I have to wait 5 seconds to see the second message ("Message received...") and 5 more seconds to see the third one.
My understanding of concurentConsumers (also described [here](https://blog.christianposta.com/camel/very-fast-camels-and-cloud-messaging/)) is that with a value of 5 I would see the 3 messages at the same time since 3 threads will consume them.
If I add the Thread.sleep in a seda route, I'm having this behavior (= The 3 messages are read at the same time).

Turning on the Camel logs it seems that the next polling is done only after the *Delete* for the previous message is made (which is with a delay of 5s).

I would understand the above behavior with concurentConsumers=1 but I don't with concurentConsumers=5. Could someone tell me what I've misunderstood ?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. I believe it relates to this defect https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-17592. According to JIRA it will be fixed in the next camel release.